# How to create training set from little but clean data?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, similarities, supervised-learning

I'm trying to learn a similarity measure based on the bottlenecks from Inception model. Basically, I want to compare two images and say if they contain exactly the same object:

1. The first image is "external", in the sense that it can have a background, the object being occluded and so on.
2. The second image is always an image of an object with little to no background, e.g. a "clean image.

I have read several papers on similar subjects (e.g. [this one](http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_iccv_2015/papers/Kiapour_Where_to_Buy_ICCV_2015_paper.pdf)) but my fundamental problem is that I only have a few clean images (around 6) of each object I'm interested to recognize but no real-world labeled images containing those objects.

So, my question: is it possible to use some kind of computer vision technique to produce "real-world" images from the clean images of the objects? Are those "produced" images a good training set for learning the similarity measure? Is there an alternative way to "grow" the training set? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could use some distortion algorithms like geometric transformations and the like.

Comment: @grldsndrs sure, but what transformations concretely?

Comment: Look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_transformation.  The idea is to get an image that could be your original image but from a different perspective.